# How to call certain view in sencha using sidebar tab button

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I have just like website, side menu. which is different menu items, I want to display if click one tab then display related information in the next view. if again click next button display in same view. only change button view  is same.

Here more clear of these images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to do this in sencha, I am very new in sencha. Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a Card layout for the main body.  See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card

For the side navigation, you can use simple components that change the active item of the card layout using listeners on the elements of the components (for example, use `singletap` event for the element: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-singletap).

```
items: [{
    items: [
        {
            html: 'Student',
            listeners: {
                initialize: function(cmp) {
                    cmp.element.on('singletap', function() {
                        Ext.getCmp('myCardLayout').setActiveItem(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            html: 'Teacher',
            listeners: {
                initialize: function(cmp) {
                    cmp.element.on('singletap', function() {
                        Ext.getCmp('myCardLayout').setActiveItem(2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 'myCardLayout',
    layout: 'card',
    items: [
        {
            //student panel
        },
        {
            //teacher panel
        }
    ]
}]
```

Note that this is pretty sloppy code (it is not MVC, it uses Ext.getCmp, etc), but it is just intended to give you the concept of what should work for you here.